# executing ODI 12c interface I am getting the error ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

When trying to run the below code in ODI12c getting the above error, I am not able to find error in the code.

Please help me on this.

```
update    <%=odiRef.getTable("L","TARG_NAME","A")%> T  
set    (  
    <%=odiRef.getColList("", "T.[COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "", "(SCD_FLAG and REW)")%>
<%if ((odiRef.getColList("", "A", "", "", "(SCD_FLAG and REW)").length() != 0) && (odiRef.getColList("", "B", "", "", "(SCD_END and REW)").length() != 0)){out.print("    ,");}%>
    <%=odiRef.getColList("", "T.[COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "", "(SCD_END and REW)")%>  
    ) =       ( 
        select    distinct <%=odiRef.getColList("", "0", ",\n\t\t\t", "", "(SCD_FLAG and REW)")%>
<%if ((odiRef.getColList("", "A", "", "", "(SCD_FLAG and REW)").length() != 0) && (odiRef.getColList("", "B", "", "", "(SCD_END and REW)").length() != 0)){out.print("            ,");}%>
<%if (odiRef.getColList("", "C", "", "", "(SCD_END and REW)").length() != 0){
    if (odiRef.getColList("", "D]", "", "", "(SCD_START and REW)").length() != 0){
        out.print(odiRef.getColList("\t\t\t", "S.[COL_NAME]", ",\n\t\t\t", "", "(SCD_START and REW)") + " - 1");
    } else {
        out.print(odiRef.getColList("\t\t\t", "sysdate", ",\n\t\t\t", "", "(SCD_END and REW)") + " - 1");
}} %>
        from    <%=odiRef.getTable("L","INT_NAME","A")%> S  
        where    <%=odiRef.getColList("", "S.[COL_NAME]\t= T.[COL_NAME]", "\n\t\tand\t", "", "SCD_NK")%>  
        and    S.IND_UPDATE     = 'I' 
        )  
where    (<%=odiRef.getColList("", "T.[COL_NAME]", ", ", "", "(SCD_NK)")%>)
    in    (  
        select    <%=odiRef.getColList("", "X.[COL_NAME]", ", ", "", "(SCD_NK)")%>  
        from    <%=odiRef.getTable("L","INT_NAME","A")%> X  
        where    X.IND_UPDATE    = 'I'  
        )  
<%=odiRef.getColList("and\t", "T.[COL_NAME]\t= 1", "\nand\t", "", "(SCD_FLAG)")%>
<%=odiRef.getColList("and\t","T.[COL_NAME]\t= to_date ('01-01-2400', 'mm-dd-yyyy')","\nand\t","","(SCD_END and REW)")%>
```

Comment: Which exact release of ODI are you using? Which LKM are you using? What's the exact name of the step? I would suggest to copy/paste the code for that step from the operator and run it in SQL Developer, Toad or any other IDE. That will allow you to run part of the code and isolate the missing table or column. Also what your are executing is a mapping, interfaces don't exist anymore in ODI12c.

Comment: The ODI 12c(12.1.3.0.0). The IKM used is customized one called as "IKM_BN_Oracle_SCD_With_History". The STEP name is "Historize old rows". When I compare the code with my present production system the column names are missing(T.LAST_APPEARED_DATE, S.FIRST_APPEARED_DATE - 1 , and LAST_APPEARED_DATE = to_date ('01-01-2400', 'mm-dd-yyyy')) from Update statement. Below is the query which I got it from present production system :

Comment: update O_DIAMOND.DIAMOND_OWNERSHIP_FACT T  
set (  
 

 T.LAST_APPEARED_DATE  
 ) =    ( 
  select distinct 

   S.FIRST_APPEARED_DATE - 1
  from SUNOPSIS_ETL.I$_DIAMOND_OWNERSHIP_FACT S  
  where S.DIAMOND_ID = T.DIAMOND_ID
  and S.DIAMOND_RETAILER_ID = T.DIAMOND_RETAILER_ID  
  and S.IND_UPDATE  = 'I' 
  )  
where (T.DIAMOND_ID, T.DIAMOND_RETAILER_ID)
 in (  
  select X.DIAMOND_ID, X.DIAMOND_RETAILER_ID  
  from SUNOPSIS_ETL.I$_DIAMOND_OWNERSHIP_FACT X  
  where X.IND_UPDATE = 'I'  
  )  

and LAST_APPEARED_DATE = to_date ('01-01-2400', 'mm-dd-yyyy')

Comment: This query is from ODI12C(12.1.3.0.0)  update    O_DIAMOND.DIAMOND_OWNERSHIP_FACT T  
set    () =       ( 
        select    distinct 
        from    SUNOPSIS_ETL.I$_DIAMOND_OWNERSHIP_FACT S  
        where    S.DIAMOND_ID = T.DIAMOND_ID
  and S.DIAMOND_RETAILER_ID = T.DIAMOND_RETAILER_ID  
        and    S.IND_UPDATE     = 'I' 
        )  
where    (T.DIAMOND_ID, T.DIAMOND_RETAILER_ID)
    in    (  
        select    X.DIAMOND_ID, X.DIAMOND_RETAILER_ID  
        from    SUNOPSIS_ETL.I$_DIAMOND_OWNERSHIP_FACT X  
        where    X.IND_UPDATE    = 'I'  
        )

Comment: Present production system is in ODI 10g(10.1.3.5.2). I am getting below error when trying to execute it is ODI12C :ODI-1228: Task Historize old rows-IKM_BN_Oracle_SCD_With_History- fails on the target connection dssprod.
Caused By: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:466)

Comment: I wouldn't expect a KM from 10g to work seamlessly in 12c. You need to review carefully the KM or even rebuild it.
Can you check that you correctly setup the SCD properties on the attributes of your datastore in the Model ?

Comment: Need help to figure our error in the code that I pasted, I am not able to get it. The SCD properties are as expected.